# Studying Finance: What topic to study after TVM?

Tags: student

Sorry for posting 2 questions in a day here.

I am new to finance, and I´m really enjoying learning.

So I´ve covered the 1st topic of Financial Maths which is the TVM (but didn´t dive deep because my school finance subject is very basic).

Now I´m learning on my own, and I want to know what´s the next topic I should learn?

Note that I don´t want to learn the theory part, just the math, because I even bought the TI BA II Plus Pro.
I´m going to learn through YT and Internet so any useful links will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Finance is a huge field of study with many different sub-fields intersecting with each other at varying rates. You could perhaps get better help if you indicated to what end you wish to learn finance.

Comment: I want to learn because I might apply to an accounting/finance college degree next year. Like I said I am most interested in the maths side of finance.

Comment: That's great! However, although I am sure there are people who have worked in finance or taught finance courses in this forum, it is most probably not appropriate to ask questions regarding studies towards a professional degree in finance here. See [this help page](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) about which topics are deemed as appropriate to be asked in this forum.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you also have had your accounting coursework, I would recommend a few very different paths.

First, I would suggest you get a copy of the 1943 version of Security Analysis by Benjamin Graham.  There is a version out there that contains notes from current analysts to bring it up to date.  I also recommend the 1987 version of the same book by Cottle and Dodd.  That will give you a good idea of investment analysis.

Second, I would recommend getting a better grounding in probability and statistics than just the single semester service course.  Freund's Introduction to Statistics would be a good choice.  It does require calculus.  If you have not had calculus, you will need calculus eventually in finance.  You can go a long way without it, such as a loan officer, but then you will hit a permanent ceiling.  If you have not had a one semester course in statistics yet, get it.  I don't think it can be self taught well.  Many of the ideas are very counter-intuitive.

Third, if you have not had calculus, then pick up "Calculus the Easy Way."  It was written in the 60s.  The book has a giant, a king, I think it has a train and lots of math told in story form.  You will get five semesters of non-rigorous calculus.  You should still take rigorous calculus, but it will give you a start.

Fourth, pick up a good book on corporate governance.  I have never taught corporate governance so I cannot recommend a book, but if you have taken TVM in a class, just find out what textbook is used where you are at.

Fifth, take the introductory courses in micro- and macroeconomics.

Comment: Great advice! Although not directly related to math, I would add that spending a considerable amount of time learning how to code is very valuable. Any position in finance that requires someone to know more than basic math will require solid coding skills as well.